Yup _.addMethod globally
I wrote method in one file with one schema.
function isNotEmptyObject() {
    return this.test("isNotEmptyObject", function (value) {
        const { path, createError } = this;
        if (isEmpty(value)) return createError({ path, message: "" });
        return true;
    });
}

yup.addMethod(yup.object, "isNotEmptyObject", isNotEmptyObject);

but want to use it in other schemas too.
How can i assign this method globally, so i can reach it from other files too?

I found solution if someone is interested, here it is :) - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-yup-global-addmethod-sample-zenn-2d494z?file=/src/yup.custom.ts

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
